# Time variable in script became negative during execution

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, floating-point, python-3.7

I have a Python program running on my Raspberry Pi 3B doing a bunch of image processing and so on. I wanted to gather some data measurements from the program by writing it into a .csv file, and I wanted to write the corresponding time with each measurement. I used `time.clock()` (see code snippet below) to find the time before each write operation, but somewhere between 2147 seconds and 2148 seconds, the time becomes negative (see snippet table below). I expect some kind over overflow occurred, but I'm having trouble understanding in which manner it overflowed. The Raspberry Pi is a 32 bit system, and as I understand, the `time.clock()` method returns a float. Shouldn't the time variable have overflowed only at much larger values, or is the time variable in this case not 32 bits?

Since then, I've read various threads that indicate `time.time()` might have been a better method for this use-case, and I might do that in future tests, but I just want to see what I can do with the values I've gathered thus far. I believe I can do some processing on the logged time to "de-overflow", for the lack of a better word, and use it as is. Any thoughts?

```
import time
import csv


def somefunction(someX, someY, csvwriter):
    t = time.clock()

    x = somefunc(someX)
    y = somefunc(someY)

    csvwriter.writerow([t, x, y])

    return
```

| Time (s) | X value | Y value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2146.978524 | -0.0019 | 0.00032 |
| 2147.30423 | -0.00191 | 0.00023 |
| -2147.336675 | -0.00182 | 0.00034 |
| -2147.000555 | -0.00164 | 0.00037 |

Comment: There is no longer a `time.clock()` function in the `time` module. Are you using Python 2? If so, you should tag your question appropriately.

Comment: @martineau I'm using Python 3.7. I'm not sure what to tell you, but I've used time.clock().

Comment: Python 3.7 still has [time.clock](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/time.html?#time.clock), it was [removed in 3.8](https://docs.python.org/3.8/whatsnew/3.8.html#api-and-feature-removals).

Comment: Before that, `time.clock()` was deprecated since version 3.3. I added a "python-3.7" tag to your question. Meanwhile, perhaps the problem would go away if you used `time.perf_counter()` or `time.process_time()` instead (as suggested in the linked What's New document). I also doubt this is an 32-bit issue, because at the beginning of the document it says "The functions in this module may not handle dates and times before the epoch or far in the future. The cut-off point in the future is determined by the C library; for 32-bit systems, it is typically in 2038."

Comment: @martineau "The cut-off point in the future is determined by the C library; for 32-bit systems, it is typically in 2038." Thank you, this provides all the information I needed. If you would put that as an answer I would like to mark it as such.

Comment: Thanks @Franz, I have done so although I don't really consider it an "answer".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I doubt this is an 32-bit issue. The third bullet point near the beginning of the Python 3.7 [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/time.html?#module-time) of the `time` module says:

> - The functions in this module may not handle dates and times before the epoch or far in the future. The cut-off point in the future is determined by the C library; for 32-bit systems, it is typically in 2038.

That said, I don't really know what the problem is. Perhaps using the `time.perf_counter()` or `time.process_time()` functions instead would avoid the issue.